# Scraping proxy IPs from a webpage using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Below is my code & i am trying to scrape proxies from site. It is scraping proxies & writing them to text file but after writing last proxy to text file it shows this error as well. What am i doing wrong here ?

```
def new():
 url = 'https://free-proxy-list.net'
 page = requests.get(url)
 # Turn the HTML into a Beautiful Soup object
 soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'lxml')

 with io.open('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\' + 'proxy.txt','a', encoding='utf8') as logfile:
      for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[1:]:
           tds = tr.find_all('td')
           logfile.write(u"%s:%s\n"%(tds[0].text,tds[1].text))
           print(u"\n%s:%s\n"%(tds[0].text,tds[1].text))
```

Error :-

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\yt bot.py", line 69, in 
    new()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\yt bot.py", line 64, in new
    logfile.write(u"%s:%s\n"%(tds[0].text,tds[1].text))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: The last tr apparently contains less than 2 tds...

Comment: why negative review me ? I was just asking because i have tried, after that i asked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the last `<tr>` looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <th class="input">
        <input type="text" />
    </th>
    ...
</tr>
```

This has nothing to do with the other entries, so you could just safely skip it:

```
for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[1:-1]:
    ...
```

Alternatively, using a `try-except` block to catch an `IndexError` would also work:

```
with io.open(...) as logfile:
    for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
        try:
            tds = tr.find_all('td')
            logfile.write(u"%s:%s\n" % (tds[0].text, tds[1].text))
        except IndexError:
            pass
```

As an aside, I would recommend using `os.path.join` to join for file paths:

```
os.path.join('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\', 'proxy.txt')
```

This is safer than simple concatenation using `+`.